# Why does the click event listener break after the first click?

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm using the angular-leaflet-directive within Ionic Framework.  I set up a listener on a map marker and it works on the first click after the page is loaded.  After that, though, it stops responding to the left mouse button (but confusingly still responds to the right mouse button).

[Here's a demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/ea988541dbfb).  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The map zoom controls are also no longer responding to click after the modal is shown once. So you may have something that prevents (left) click event from firing in Leaflet.

Comment: It seems to be the ng-click directive that triggers the error.  I've tried moving it to different elements, or switching to ng-mousedown, but the Leaflet event listeners always break after it's triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same issue, use `data-tap-disabled="true"` in the tag `leaflet` worked to me.

Comment: My demo is dead (for some reason) and I wound up switching to angular-google-maps instead, so I don't have an easy way to confirm this, but I'll go ahead and mark it as the answer.  Thanks for sharing!